# Use two font in latex

Tags: xetex, xepersian

I'm completely new to Latex/XeLatex and I want to use two different font in my document:
I want to write Persian letters in ***'B Zar'*** font family and English letters in ***'Times New Roman'*** font family.

Also I want to change math font to ***'Times New Roman'*** too.

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{B Zar} 

\begin{document}
 سلام

Hello 
 
$$ a + b = 3$$
\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

As you can see The Persian font family is set correctly and I'm looking for a similar command to set the Mathematical and English font as simple as possible. what can I do? Is it possible in XeLatex at all?

I'm using XeLatex, texMaker as my editor and I'm on Linux OS(KDE Manjaro ).
UPDATES:

**What I've tried already**:

For changing math font:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xepersian}  
\settextfont{B Zar} 
\DeclareMathAlphabet {\foo}{OT1}{Times New Roman}{}{}
\SetMathAlphabet\foo{normal}{OT1}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
 سلام

Hello 
 
$$ a + b = 3$$
\end{document}
```

But No change in output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xepersian} 

\settextfont{Scheherazade}
\setlatintextfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
 سلام

\begin{latin}
Hello 
\end{latin}
\[
a + b = 3
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. Just one more question: Is it possible to write English words in inline mode? I mean I want to use English words along Persian Lines but "latin" block creates a new line.